# How to use retrofit in Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, retrofit, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to make an API call using retrofit in Flutter I have already included the following libraries in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:    
 retrofit: ^1.3.4+1
 json_annotation: ^3.1.1
 dio: ^3.0.10
 logger: ^0.9.4
 built_value: ^7.1.0

dev_dependencies:
 retrofit_generator: ^1.4.1
 build_runner: ^1.10.0
 json_serializable: ^3.5.0
 built_value_generator: ^7.1.0
```

and created the following class api_client.dart

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/")
abstract class ApiClient {
  factory ApiClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _ApiClient;

}
```

I have also generated the api_client.g.dart

```
part of 'api_client.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RetrofitGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class _ApiClient implements ApiClient {
  _ApiClient(this._dio, {this.baseUrl}) {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(_dio, '_dio');
    baseUrl ??= 'https://gorest.co.in/public-api/';
  }

  final Dio _dio;

  String baseUrl;
}
```

and that's it I'm stuck.Now I don't know how to make the Get and Post calls can somebody help me out with this

1. How to make a Get request?
2. How to make a Post request and how to give body the values?
3. How to handle the responses from the API?
4. How to use basic authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit in flutter:

Dependencies for project:

```
    dependencies:
       flutter:
     sdk: flutter
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      dio: ^4.0.0
      json_serializable: ^4.1.4
      retrofit: ^2.0.0
      logger: ^1.0.0
      json_annotation: ^4.0.1
      retrofit_generator: ^2.0.0+3
      build_runner: ^2.0.5
```

ApiRequest.dart file

```
  @RestApi(baseUrl: "https://gorest.co.in/public-api/")
  abstract class ApiRequest{
  factory ApiRequest(Dio dio,{required String baseUrl}) =_ApiRequest;

  @GET("/users")
  Future<ResponseData> getUsers();

  }
```

apirequest.g.dart file code:

```
   part of 'apirequest.dart';

   class _ApiRequest implements ApiRequest {
         _ApiRequest(this._dio, {required this.baseUrl}) {
             ArgumentError.checkNotNull(_dio, '_dio');
             this.baseUrl = 'https://gorest.co.in/public-api/';
   }

   final Dio _dio;

   String baseUrl;

   @override
   getUsers() async {
       const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
       final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
       final _data = <String, dynamic>{};

       var options=Options(
            receiveTimeout: 1000,sendTimeout: 1000,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: <String, dynamic>{},
            extra: _extra,

       );
      final _result = await _dio.request('$baseUrl/users',
             queryParameters: queryParameters,
             options: options,

             data: _data);
      final value = ResponseData.fromJson(_result.data);
      return value;
     }
    }
```

I have a solution with complete source code updated on Github. You can get code by my Github account link is here.

https://github.com/NishaJain24/Retrofit_Flutter

Answer (score 1):

api_client.dart

```
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import 'model.dart';

part 'api_client.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
abstract class APIClient {
  factory APIClient(Dio dio) = _APIClient;

  @POST("/posts")
  Future<PostResponse> postDemo(@Body() PostRequest dataPost);
}
```

model.dart

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class PostRequest {
  PostRequest({
    this.title,
    this.body,
    this.userId,
  });

  String? title;
  String? body;
  String? userId;

  factory PostRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PostRequestFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PostRequestToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class PostResponse {
  PostResponse({
    this.title,
    this.body,
    this.userId,
    this.id,
  });

  String? title;
  String? body;
  String? userId;
  int? id;

  factory PostResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PostResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PostResponseToJson(this);
}
```

repo_class.dart

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

import 'api_client.dart';
import 'model.dart';

class RepoClass {
  late APIClient mClient;
  RepoClass() {
    mClient = APIClient(Dio());
  }

  demoPost() async {
    PostRequest dataPost = PostRequest(
        title: 'This is Title',
        body: 'This is Body',
        userId: 'This is User Id');
    var posResponse = await mClient.postDemo(dataPost);
    print('${posResponse.id}:  ${posResponse.title}');
    //You can use your login model data as per your requirements.
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipes/repo_class.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Retrofit Demo - Flutter"),
      ),
      body: pressed
          ? Text('Body')
          : Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Fetch Post",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () => {
                        setState(() {
                          RepoClass repoClass = RepoClass();
                          repoClass.demoPost();
                        })
                      }),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  retrofit: ^2.0.0
  logger: ^1.0.0
  dio:
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  json_serializable: ^4.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  retrofit_generator: ^2.0.0+3
  build_runner: ^2.0.5
  analyzer:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

don't forget to run this command to generate g.dart

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

full example here:
https://github.com/HienNguyen102/flutter_retrofit

Comment: The model class is generated manually or it is also built by retrofit build command

Comment: @Fluttydev, model.dart I generated manually

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this article; he explain how to use retrofit in a Flutter App:

https://medium.com/mindful-engineering/retrofit-the-easiest-way-to-call-rest-apis-is-flutter-fe55d1e7c5c2

Comment: I have already looked at this article but it doesn't answer my question.I actually came up with this questions after trying out this article.